# how can i override functions ( create, delete, modify, etc ) of crudify class ( scala with lift )

Tags: api, scala, rest, lift

as above a title

i use the lift ( scala ) with jetty web server

i wanted to develop rest api . as fast as possible.

so i extended crudify ( trait )

finally , i can get results that are html web pages

now..

i want to get form that is json or xml format

i don't need html code.

i just want format of json or xml.

how can i modify  this source code extending crudify

may be . i think that overriding some functions of crudify.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Crudify is **not** the right solution for a REST API. You should have a look at the [REST Web Services](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/REST_Web_Services) page in the Lift wiki. To create XML documents automatically, maybe you should have a look at [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above CRUDify is for HTML not for JSON nor XML. To represent your mapper object as a xml or json use: toXml and asJs functions. The other way you have to add parse functions that convert values posted by user into mapper objects.